# bootstrap-select does not have any effect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I found bootstrap-select, but I am not able to get a nice drop-down menu shown [here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/master/test.html). Where could I do anything wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="lunch">Lunch: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
    <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
    <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
    <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
    <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
<div>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting any console errors???

Comment: No, I did not call select with javascript (see please solution below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling select with javascript. Use this code instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="lunch">Lunch: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
    <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
    <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
    <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
    <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
<div>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```